# Laravel -, Can't update more than one record using Fetch Api

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, fetch

I want to update my multiple records. But only first record is updating, other ones aren't..

I'm using fetch api for ajax call, but I thins problem is not here, cause I'm able to send array data, I can see in browser dev section. (I mean, I can send multiple id data, it's ok)

Then I'm trying to save them in foreach loop, but only first record is updating in this loop.

in controller

```
 public function approveComment(Request $request)
    {
      if ($request->ajax()) {
          $ids = $request->json()->all();
            foreach ($ids as $id) {
                $comment = Comments::find($id);
                $comment->comment_status = 1;
                $comment->save();
            }
    return response()->json("successful");
      } else {
          $comment = Comments::find($request->input('comment_id'));
          $comment->comment_status = 1;
          $comment->save();
          return back();
      }
    }
```

ajax call;

```
ajax.put('comments/approve',token,ids)
      .then(data => data.json())
      .then(log => console.log(log))
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

put method in ajax class

```
 async put(url, token, data) {

        const response = await fetch(url, {
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Accept": "application/json",
                "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
                "X-CSRF-Token": token
            },
            method: "put",
            credentials: "same-origin",
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
        });
        return response;
    }
```

Comment: Does `$ids` contain the expected values?

Comment: I checked it on dev console. It have comments ids as json

Answer (score 0):

I find the problem;

```
 public function approveComment(Request $request)
    {
      if ($request->ajax()) {
          $ids = $request->json()->all();
            foreach ($ids as $id) {
                $comment = Comments::find($id);
                $comment->comment_status = 1;
                $comment->save();
   //  return response()->json("successful"); (it was here)
            }
    return response()->json("successful"); (it should be in here, not in loop)
      } else {
          $comment = Comments::find($request->input('comment_id'));
          $comment->comment_status = 1;
          $comment->save();
          return back();
      }
    }
```